# Can I use class variable in class method in Java?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I'm learning Java and practicing by myself.
I tried to make a class variable `String username` and I thought I would get the result
"Hi Nat" since method `engHi()` is in the same class with the variable.

```
class Greetings{
    String userName = "Nat";
    public static void engHi(String userName){
        System.out.println("Hi "+userName);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greetings.engHi();
    }
}
```

And I got this message.

```
Error:(11, 18) java: method engHi in class com.company.Greetings cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

and then I added `this.username = username` in the method `engHi()`

```
class Greetings{
    String userName = "Nat";
    public static void engHi(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
        System.out.println("Hi "+userName);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greetings.engHi();
    }
}
```

And the result is

```
Error:(12, 18) java: method engHi in class com.company.Greetings cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I thought since the method is in the same class I thought the method was gonna take the variable username 'automatically' so I didn't put any parameter when I called the method.
So.. It means methods don't take any variable from same class?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code here is that your method `engHi()` requires the a username string to be sent in as a parameter.  If you remove the parameters of `engHi()`, this error should go away.

```
class Greetings{
    String userName = "Nat";
    public static void engHi(){ //nothing required to be passed in when you call engHi()
        System.out.println("Hi "+userName);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greetings.engHi();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add a userame in call like `Greetings.engHi("Nat");` or remove that from acceptig function like

```
public static void engHi(){
}
```

Your methof engHi is expecting a username which you're not passing during the call from `Greetings.engHi();`

Answer (score 0):

The error has little to do with using class variables.

Rather, if a method is declared with *N* arguments, it needs to be called with *N* arguments.

Declaration: `engHi(String userName)` - 1 argument.

Call: `Greetings.engHi()` - 0 arguments.

The mismatch in argument count is a language violation.

Moreover, in these two lines:

```
String userName = "Nat";
public static void engHi(String userName){
```

the two occurences of `username` are not referring to the same thing. The first declares a member of an instance of the class; the second is a formal argument of the `engHi` method, which will be set to whatever value is provided as an actual argument by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

A `static` method may only access `static` variables. A non-`static` method may access `static` and non-`static` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of the Greetings class in engHi() method.

```
 public static void engHI() { 
   Greetings greetings = new Greetings(); 
   System.out.println("Hi " + greetings.userName);
}
```